# Gradient of FFT over variables fails

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

In Tensorflow, the following code fails with an error `ValueError: Shapes (3, 32, 28, 28) and () are not compatible`

```
import tensorflow as tf

filters = 32
width = 28
height = 28
channels = 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels])
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([channels, filters, height, width], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32]))

w_ifft = tf.real(tf.batch_ifft2d(tf.complex(w, 0.0)))
w_ifft_transpose = tf.transpose(w_ifft, [2, 3, 0, 1])

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w_ifft_transpose, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
output = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b)

print tf.gradients(output, w)
```

Although this is a simplified example to illustrate the error, I am using iffts on variables to parameterize convolutional filters in the frequency domain as described in [Spectral Representations for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://hips.seas.harvard.edu/files/rippel-spectral-nips-2015.pdf)

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using? I ran it with 0.9.0 and this code prints out `[<tf.Tensor 'gradients/Complex_grad/Reshape:0' shape=(3, 32, 28, 28) dtype=float32>]`.

Comment: 0.9.0 -- did you try the most recently edited version of the code?

Comment: Yes, seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, tensorflow 0.9.0 (installed via pip), cuda 7.5, cudnn 4.0.7

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the shape of `w_ifft_transpose` is `[height, width, channels, filters]`, and then you use `tf.nn.conv2d` which is right in my PC.
[python 3.5.5 tensorflow version 1.1.0, cuda 8.0, cudnn 6.0]

Actually, the parameters' number of your `w` is far larger than traditional 3*3 convolution and that you use `ifft2d` is meaningless due to not exist complex number